# Firestore add social login to database

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Anyone have a suggestion on how to make this work. I have a Facebook login, and if there is no data for this user write data.

```
let users = firebase.usersCollection;


signUserInFacebook () {
const self = this;
var provider = new Firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
Firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
 .then(function(user) {
  usersRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(user.email).once('value', 
   function(snapshot){
    var exist = (snapshot.val() !== null);

     if(!exist){
      users.add(user)
      }
    }

})
```

},

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this

1. If you have the user's email (must be unique) as part of their info, you can do this

   ```
           //check if this is first sign in, if yes save new user to db
       userRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(user.email).once('value', function(snapshot){
           var exist = (snapshot.val() !== null);

           if(!exist){
             //add new user here
           }
   ```

   I usually like to set the uid of a newly created user as their key, so I can use them whenever I need to query for a user instead of using a unique value like email.

Comment: Using Firestore.